# Displaying a PDF from Google Drive in Flutter(Preferably without GDrive authentication)

Tags: flutter, pdf, dart

I am currently using the Plugin flutter_plugin_pdf_viewer in Flutter. I want to take a link from Google Drive and then display it in the Flutter application. The code works with PDFs found on the internet, but not PDFs from Drive. I have also made sure that the PDF is accessible to anyone with the link. Would it be possible in anyway to alter the code such that I would not have to integrate any Google Drive authentication in the app?

Here is the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_plugin_pdf_viewer/flutter_plugin_pdf_viewer.dart';

class ArticlePDFViewer extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = '/article-pdf';
  @override
  _ArticlePDFViewerState createState() => _ArticlePDFViewerState();
}

class _ArticlePDFViewerState extends State<ArticlePDFViewer> {
  String url =
      "https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PZTtv7lAvwa5iNw2tITF9sXXg6KL2JPh/preview";
  PDFDocument _doc;
  bool _loading;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _initPDF();
  }

  _initPDF() async {
    setState(() {
      _loading = true;
    });
    final doc = await PDFDocument.fromURL(url);
    setState(() {
      _doc = doc;
      _loading = false;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Example PDF"),
      ),
      body: _loading
          ? Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            )
          : PDFViewer(
              document: _doc,
            ),
    );
  }
}
```

And here is the error message I am getting:

```
W/System.err(26891): java.io.IOException: file not in PDF format or corrupted
W/System.err(26891):    at android.graphics.pdf.PdfRenderer.nativeCreate(Native Method)
W/System.err(26891):    at android.graphics.pdf.PdfRenderer.<init>(PdfRenderer.java:166)
W/System.err(26891):    at pt.tribeiro.flutter_plugin_pdf_viewer.FlutterPluginPdfViewerPlugin.getNumberOfPages(FlutterPluginPdfViewerPlugin.java:88)
W/System.err(26891):    at pt.tribeiro.flutter_plugin_pdf_viewer.FlutterPluginPdfViewerPlugin.access$000(FlutterPluginPdfViewerPlugin.java:28)
W/System.err(26891):    at pt.tribeiro.flutter_plugin_pdf_viewer.FlutterPluginPdfViewerPlugin$1.run(FlutterPluginPdfViewerPlugin.java:59)
W/System.err(26891):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
W/System.err(26891):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
W/System.err(26891):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
W/System.err(26891):    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
E/flutter (26891): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(166)] Unhandled Exception: Exception: Error reading PDF!
E/flutter (26891): #0      PDFDocument.fromURL (package:flutter_plugin_pdf_viewer/src/document.dart:46:7)
E/flutter (26891): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (26891): #1      _ArticlePDFViewerState._initPDF (package:whaapp2/screens/articles/article_pdf_viewer.dart:26:35)
E/flutter (26891): #2      _ArticlePDFViewerState.initState (package:whaapp2/screens/articles/article_pdf_viewer.dart:19:5)
E/flutter (26891): #3      StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4684:58)
E/flutter (26891): #4      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4520:5)
E/flutter (26891): #5      Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3490:14)
E/flutter (26891): #6      Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3258:18)
E/flutter (26891): #7      SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5874:14)
E/flutter (26891): #8      Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3490:14)
E/flutter (26891): #9      Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3258:18)
E/flutter (26891): #10     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4571:16)
E/flutter (26891): #11     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4262:5)
E/flutter (26891): #12     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4525:5)
E/flutter (26891): #13     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4520:5)
E/flutter (26891): #14     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3490:14)
E/flutter (26891): #15     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3258:18)
E/flutter (26891): #16     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5874:14)
E/flutter (26891): #17     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3490:14)
E/flutter (26891): #18     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3258:18)
E/flutter (26891): #19     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5874:14)
E/flutter (26891): #20     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3490:14)
E/flutter (26891): #21     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3258:18)
E/flutter (26891): #22     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4571:16)
E/flutter (26891): #23     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4719:11)
E/flutter (26891): #24     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4262:5)
E/flutter (26891): #25     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4525:5)
E/flutter (26891): #26     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4710:11)
E/flutter (26891): #27     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4520:5)
E/flutter (26891): #28     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3490:14)
E/flutter (26891): #29     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3258:18)
E/flutter (26891): #30     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5874:14)
E/flutter (26891): #31     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3490:14)
E/flutter (26891): #32     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3258:18)
E/flutter (26891): #33     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5874:14)
E/flutter (26891): #34     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3490:14)
E/flutter (26891): #35     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3258:18)
E/flutter (26891): #36     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4571:16)
E/flutter (26891): #37     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4719:11)
E/flutter (26891): #38     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4262:5)
E/flutter (26891): #39     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4525:5)
E/flutter (26891): #40     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4710:11)
E/flutter (26891): #41     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4520:5)
E/flutter (26891): #42     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3490:14)
E/flutter (26891): #43     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3258:18)
E/flutter (26891): #44     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4571:16)
E/flutter (26891): #45     Element.rebuild
E/System  (26891): Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer
E/System  (26891): java.io.IOException: file not in PDF format or corrupted
E/System  (26891):  at android.graphics.pdf.PdfRenderer.nativeClose(Native Method)
E/System  (26891):  at android.graphics.pdf.PdfRenderer.doClose(PdfRenderer.java:250)
E/System  (26891):  at android.graphics.pdf.PdfRenderer.finalize(PdfRenderer.java:238)
E/System  (26891):  at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:250)
E/System  (26891):  at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.runInternal(Daemons.java:237)
E/System  (26891):  at java.lang.Daemons$Daemon.run(Daemons.java:103)
E/System  (26891):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Comment: Are these PDFs from Drive visible to public? I.e are they supposed to be public so that anyone can accesss them or do you want only a few people to be able to access these PDFs from Drive?

Comment: Yes, they are public. In Google Drive, I have enabled the sharing to "anyone with the link can see it"

Comment: Then you shouldn need to authentificate to display them. Could you try using the following url path and let me know what that shows ```https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PZTtv7lAvwa5iNw2tITF9sXXg6KL2JPh```? Also if that does not work could you try the following url ```https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PZTtv7lAvwa5iNw2tITF9sXXg6KL2JPh/view```? Thanks ! :D

Comment: This leads to the same error message as before about how the file is not in PDF format

Comment: Hi, are you able to solve it? I am trying to display pdf in my flutter app too from gdrive

Comment: @ZXERSTON No, I was not able to solve it